# Collection of entities (and textarea) in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a very simple form (**ModuleType.php**) calling a collection (**ModuleControleType.php**).

**This code works perfectly** (add, modify and delete : no problem), but I want to customize the query for find *Description* (I just want to add a Where) in **ModuleControleType.php**.

I can do a query_builder with a field of type " *Entity* ", but not with a field " *Collection* " type.

**ModuleType.php :**

```
class ModuleType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('point', 'textarea', array(
                'label' => 'Point(s) à observer',
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'rows' => 5
                )
            ))
            ->add('controles', 'collection', array(
                'label' => false,
                'type' => new ModuleControleType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false
            ))
        ;
    }
```

**ModuleControleType.php :**

```
class ModuleControleType extends AbstractType
{

    use Description;

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('description', 'textarea', array(
                'label' => 'Description',
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'rows' => $rows
                )
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AdministrationBundle\Entity\ModuleControle',
            'intention' => $this->getName() . '_token'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'administration_module_controle_form';
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use a query_builder and add a `IN` or `NOT IN` predicate (you didn't specified the logic behind the query)

Comment: Yes, I know query_builder, i but I can do a query_builder with a field of type " Entity ", but not with a field " Collection " type. :-S

Comment: No, you're mistaking: a Collection could be "splitted" with IN clause ;)

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand for query_builder in Collection, do you have a little example please ?

Comment: You can iterate onto collection, extract, for example, all IDS and use NOT IN or IN (are SQL concept) to EXCLUDE or INCLUDE what you need.

Comment: I know we can put In mysql IN and NOT IN, but with symfony, I can not call a specific method of repository width Collection type :)

Comment: Who said? It's not true. Of course you can't call doctrine's magic methods but you can always write your owns :)

Comment: Okay, but where to put the request ?

Comment: Thanks but Collection type don't have "query_builder" option : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html :-S

Comment: You don't get the point here... Please explain in depth what you're trying to reach here ans, maybe, I can help you in a more concrete way.

Comment: As explained in the first post, I have FormType for adding multiple textarea. Textarea these are saving in a database. Code in first message works perfectly : no problem for add, update and remove. But I want to customize the query find existing textarea : and no query_builder in collection Type. Please see the first post if you want, it's really simple :)

Comment: If you have a soluce ... thanks ... :)